# How to write SQL statement to flatten multiple records down to a single record?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with multiple grouped by fields as shown in first table.  I'm struggling to even start the query statement to how to make it look like the second table.  Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
GRP      SET       Start     Completed
A         1       3/1/2019
A         2       3/2/2019   3/5/2019
B         1       4/1/2019   4/2/2019
B         2       2/13/2019  2/27/2019
```

Desired:

```
GRP      SET1_Start    SET1_Comp   SET2_Start   SET2_Comp
A         3/1/2019                  3/2/2019     3/5/2019
B         4/1/2019     4/2/2019     2/13/2019    2/27/2019
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Comment: Another option for creating pivot tables is [`TRANSFORM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/transform-statement-microsoft-access-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation, which uses `iif()` in MS Access:

```
select grp,
       max(iif(set = 1, start, null)) as set1_start,
       max(iif(set = 1, completed, null)) as set1_completed,
       max(iif(set = 2, start, null)) as set2_start,
       max(iif(set = 2, completed, null)) as set2_completed
from t
group by grp;
```